# Long working directory in bash when Docker desktop is running in WSL2

Tags: docker, windows-10, wsl-2

I have Docker Desktop running with WSL 2 backend. I also have Ubuntu 20.04 installed as my default WSL2 Linux distro.
The problem I am facing is that if I launch `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe` when Docker is running then the shell is initialized with a very long directory path:
`/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/8a5edab282632443219e051e4ade2d1d5bbc671c781051bf1437897cbdfea0f1/mnt/c/Windows/System32`

However, if I shutdown docker and start a WSL shell again, then it starts at the expected path: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32`

I can cd into /mnt/c myself but it is annoying that it doesn't start on the right path.
I also tried running `wsl -d "Ubuntu-20.04` to no avail.
It seems that my C volume is mounted on both /mnt/c and the long ugly path above.

Has anyone experienced and resolved this issue?

Docker Version: 2.3.0.3 (45519)

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7431

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Docker desktop version 3.1.0 (51484). Tried shutting down docker and wsl. Then restarted wsl and all worked fine. But as soon as I restarted docker, the long path reappeared.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6464

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work okay if I start Docker desktop first and then WSL.

Comment: restarting WSL helped here too, doing `wsl --shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what fixed it:

0. Let's name the folder that mounts with a long name - FL
1. Delete all the containters in Docker, that are linked to FL
2. Restart Docker
3. Inside FL run docker-compose BUT not inside WSL, but on Windows terminal.
4. Now when you mount FL into WSL by running command like "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu" - it mounts with a short name.

In summary: the problem for me was an accidental recreating of Docker containers inside my project's folder being in WSL terminal.

Answer (score -2):

I've solved this issue by disabling WSL integration option in Docker settings in Windows at Settings > Resources > WSL Integration

Comment: That is not a valid solution if you are using Docker with WSL2.

Comment: This made it worse for me when I tried it, I had to turn it back on.